# Decreasing SNMP update timer on IOS-XR (CISCO ASR)

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, snmp

I've a case where i'm trying to poll SNMP information every 10 seconds from a Cisco IOS-XR devices (interfaces mib). Seems like CISCO IOS-XR updates SNMP information every 15secs, so sometimes management platform (in this situation - Prometheus) reads the same information twice.

I know that one of the ways would be increase SNMP polling time from 10S to at least 15s. But we can't do that. Is there any workaround to make a Cisco IOS-XR refresh SNMP information more frequently than 15secs ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one helped: `snmp-server ifmib internal cache max-duration 0`

Comment: In my experience there will still be some caching done by your router (~30 seconds last time I checked)

Answer (score 5):

For short interval polling it would be better to use streaming telemetry. The router will send a continuous stream for metrics of your choice, which is not as intensive for your monitoring system and produces more reliable data than polling at an interval.

There are some nice off the shelf examples provided by Cisco on [how to integrate with Prometheus](https://developer.cisco.com/codeexchange/github/repo/cisco/bigmuddy-network-telemetry-stacks/)

For more information: [Cisco docs on Telemetry](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/iosxr/asr9000/telemetry/b-telemetry-cg-asr9000-61x.html)